# JavaFx, how to understand the rotation angle of transforms?

Tags: java, javafx

I implemented a timeline including a rotate: `.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(0.75, new Point3D(1,0,0)));`

Now I would like to do a reverse. Could anyone show me how to calculate the corresponding rotation angle? I feel a little confused.

Comment: Isn't it just `-0.75`? Or am I completely misunderstanding? (Also, note the angle is in degrees, so `0.75` is going to be barely perceptible.)

Comment: @James_D  wow...I just retried using -0.75 and I think you are right...Actually I used -0.75 at first but due to a stupid mistake the effect was not appropriate. Then I was wondering if -0.75 is correct...

Comment: Also note that if you are "undoing" an existing rotation, it would be better to remove the rotation from the transforms list than to add a second rotation that "cancels" the first.

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your commend. But I would like to perform the "play back" function. :-)